# Improve the sql query in Crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am building a Crystal report.  The query is from a huge table, but I can only read and cannot add index. The table looks like:

```
SampleTable (PersonID INT, Country VARCHAR(10), Purchase Real, PurchaseDateTime DateTime)
```

Here `PersonID` is a key (Index), but I need to query something unrelated to PersonID:

```
SELECT  Country
       , Sum(Purchase) As Purchase
 FROM  SampleTable
 WHERE PurchaseDateTime >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
 AND   PurchaseDateTime <  '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY Country
```

It runs very very slow if I do it in the above way in Crystal reports.  How can I do it faster?

Comment: Group By & Comparing date time are relatively time consuming.

Comment: Without indexes you can't. You could move the data into a reporting database and optimise that for your needs and then report from that. Sort of a datawarehouse type approach, you would of course take a hit keeping the reporting db up to date. How you address that depedsn on how up to date your report has to be.

Comment: Have you run above query from crystal reports? or just you run on database?

Comment: I cannot run on database, because I can only access the table from Crystal reports.

Comment: The report request is to get previous month purchase for each country, so I use compare the relative time and GROUP BY Country.

Comment: It looks I cannot move the table data only using Crystal Report.  Also, that table is so hugh.  If I move it, the time might be comparable to run the query.

Comment: If you were to go down that route. You'd have some task (over night ?) to create the reporting db from the one you are currently reading, then you'd point crystal reports at it. You would never move tables in a crystal report, that would be barking mad.

Comment: one suggestion is to remove `Group by` from query and group in crystal reports.. if that doesn't work then you need to seriously tune the database to get the results faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is perfect. You probably cannot speed it up by re-writing it somehow. There will always be a full table scan done on the table when executing your query. Even with an index on PurchaseDateTime this would probably not change, as there are millions of seconds in a month, so the dbms might still find it better to go for a full table scan. The only option I see is: If your dbms supports query hints, you may speed up the query by running it in parallel threads. Here is how you would do it in Oracle:

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(SampleTable,4) */
  Country,
  Sum(Purchase) As Purchase
 FROM  SampleTable
 WHERE PurchaseDateTime >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
 AND   PurchaseDateTime <  '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY Country;
```

The only other way to speed this up is changes in the database or hardware.

Database guys might be able to set a table option such that selects get executed in several parallel threads. That would speed up your execution time without any changes on your side. Or they might be able to install a function index based on `to_char(PurchaseDateTime,'yyyymm')` or whatever function the dbms offers to get the month. Then you would replace your select criteria by `WHERE to_char(PurchaseDateTime,'yyyymm') = '201304'`. This would be the best option here anyway.

Or someone might be so nice as to buy faster hardware.

If all this is out of question then there is no possibility to get your query any faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you guys think if I first put everything that I needs into a smaller table, and then sum that table will be helpful? For example, I retrieve April data for the columns I need into #temp1, and then do the sum on #temp1?  Of course, these are donw in the same Crystal report.